# How to draw dotted line around circular JButton?

Tags: java, swing

I have a couple of JButtons here and I would like to surround have a dashed border as the perimeter of each button. However. I can't figure out how to do it. Similar questions on stack overflow has been resolved with BorderFactory.createDashedBorder() but that creates a square boarder in my case.

[image]

Here is the code for how I am currently implementing the buttons. Also, I am very new to Swing so I appreciate it if the solution can be as simple as possible

```
public class ColorButton extends JButton {
    private Color color;

    public ColorButton(Color color) {
        super();
        this.color = color;
        setOpaque(false);
        setFocusable(false);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setBorderPainted(false);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(45, 45));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int diameter = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(getWidth() / 2 - diameter / 2, getHeight() / 2 - diameter / 2, diameter, diameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to use g.drawArc for each dot/dash

Comment: So the other thing is that even though you've made the button to look round, it will still respond to click events like it is a rectangle. BTW, if you are looking for a true solution for round buttons, there is one here: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `BasicStroke` to draw the oval.

Something like:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[] { 5 }, 0));
g2d.setColor(...);
g.drawOval(getWidth() / 2 - diameter / 2, getHeight() / 2 - diameter / 2, diameter, diameter);
```